# Javascript new date is 15 days off

Tags: javascript, datetime

The purpose of this function is to return the current date.  Why would this function return a date that is 15 days ago.  Tested in FF and Chrome.

```
 function whatTime() {
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var datetime = (currentdate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + currentdate.getDay() + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + (currentdate.getMinutes()&lt;10?'0':'') + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + (currentdate.getSeconds()&lt;10?'0':'') + currentdate.getSeconds();
    return datetime.toLocaleString();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.getDay()` returns the *day of the week*, not the day of the *month*.

[MDN documentation: Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Use `Date.getDate()` instead.

[MDN documentation: Date.getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

Comment: Thank you for a full and complete answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe getDay() returns the day of the week, not the actual day.